# Conditional Formatting Custom Formula: If certain cells in a row says "false", then they should be highlighted in red

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

What I'm trying to do is to highlight rows L to P in red if all cells say "False", and here is the formula I used:

```
=(sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($L2:$P2, "False")))) = 5)
```

This does not work unfortunately. I also tried the following formula (another way to put it) without any luck either:

```
=(sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($L2:$P2, "True|Unsure")))) = 0)
```

Next, is a snapshot of the conditional format rule:

[image]

Please help me figure out why the above formulas aren't working. If you need to see the sheet I'm working on, I've made a copy [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FOZFd1Ra_L4wnI0yiss-R0zyGao6sU3S-a3UNZHPys/edit#gid=1186099117).

Comment: I just changed the share option and should no longer ask for permission request. Apologies for this.

Comment: Please consider to do your tests on another copy instead of the one linked to the question. The current version has no/yes instead of false/true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

1. FALSE and TRUE are Google Sheets keywords, they represent the respective boolean values. To use them as text, use `'` as prefix, In the regular expression  change False to FALSE.
2. The "Apply to range" start cell should be L2 instead of L1.

## Explanation

### Apply to range

The relative references in custom formatting formulas takes the start cell as the pivot. As the values FALSE/TRUE/Unsure start on row 2, on Apply to range instead of using L1 as the start cell, use L2.

### Custom formula

The formula

```
=(sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($L2:$P2, "False")))) = 5)
```

returns `#VALUE!` and the following error description:

> **Error**
> Function REGEXMATCH parameter 1 expects text values. But 'FALSE' is a boolean and cannot be coerced to a text.

Note: To see the above error message in a Google Sheets spreadsheet, add the above formula to any cell not in the columns L-P

As REGEX is case sensitive the formula to use is:

```
 =(sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($L2:$P2, "FALSE")))) = 5)
```

An alternative formula to avoid the use of prefix is the following

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(IF($L2:$P2,1,0),1))=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ruben. I did try the suggested formulas but they didn't work. In the spreadsheet, rows 2, 3 and 11 should be highlighted in red but using the formulas gave different output. I've also considered replacing true or false with yes and no, respectively just to make it simpler but still no luck. If you could check the spreadsheet, I've created sheets for formula 1, 2 and 3 (with yes and no instead of true or false) so you can see how the spreadsheet interpreted the different. formulas. Thanks.

Comment: I made copy of your file yesterday. The formulas work fine on that copy on that copy. Today, the link on the question requires to request permission to access it.

Comment: I think that I figured out what it the problem and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The custom formula should only be applied to columns L to P and not the entire row.

Comment: The question title confused me. I rolled back the answer and updated the question title.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. Thanks for updating the title question. As for the spreadsheet, you were probably looking at sheet 3 with the yes/no instead of true/false. If you check sheet 1 and 2 on the same spreadsheet, you'll see that I applied the formula as you suggested.

Comment: To prevent this kind of confusions, it's better to keep the demo spreadsheet with only the required to show the problem describen on the question.

Comment: Added added notes about the apply to range field.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Ruben. The alternative formula, =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(IF($L2:$P2,1,0),1))=0) worked perfect! I just added the formula: len(L2)* in front so it applies to non-blank cells only.